# Approximate solution to maximizing a convex function

Tags: optimization, algorithms, approximation, non-convex-optimization

I need your expertise in understanding or obtaining an algorithm for obtaining an approximation to the global supremum of a convex function $f$ over a convex set $X$.
This problem is known to be $\textit{NP-Hard}$, so I wonder whether someone has attained an approximation to the problem or may have solved it under certain constraints in polynomial time (of course).

Would you know of such algorithm?

E.g. Given a convex set $S$ and an ellipsoid $E = (A,c)$ which is contained in $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to find the farthest point from the ellipsoid which is not contained in the ellipsoid, hence the following in needed:
$$ \arg\max_{x \in S}\  (x-c)^T A (x-c)$$
where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a positive definite matrix.

please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a black-box algorithm for ANY convex function and convex set? Or do you have specific problems in mind, with specific structure? Considerations like smoothness and differentiability are generally important when determining appropriate algorithms...

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: If you simply want code, I believe pycvx can do problems of this sort relatively fast. Perhaps the docs would be a good place to look for methods. Your problem looks relatively smooth, you can gradient descent for some number of rounds to approximate

Comment: Does your form of $S$ have a simple to generate explicit form? I.e., can you rewrite $S$ (in polynomial time) in terms of inequality constraints using convex functions and equality constraints using affine functions? If so, your problem can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Let $S$ be a sublevel set of a convex function $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$, how can i solve the problem in polynomial time?

Comment: N.B.: If $A$ is +ve definite and $S$ is a general polyhedron (i.e constraints formed by linear inequalities), then polynomial-time-solvable!

Comment: And regarding the way $S$ is defined above i.e. $S$ being a sublevel set of a convex function?

Comment: Are your constraint function twice differentiable? If so many out of the box solvers can handle your problem directly. Otherwise, you might have to get creative to determine a valid differentiable barrier function.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem isn't NP in general, but ofc it depends on how $S$ is constructed. If $S$ is given by some nice, differentiable function, then it's just a matter of finding points on $\partial S$ at which the KKT conditions are satisfied - loosely speaking, points at which the gradient of $f(x)$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of $S$.

Of course, these points will not all be global (or even local) maxima, but one of them should be - thus you just have to exhaustively search all KKT points on the boundary of $S$ and therefore any algorithm that is based on finding KKT points will do just fine (which in turn simply amounts to finding solutions to some particular set of linear/nonlinear equations).

Comment: Can elaborate regarding the algorithms?
Also, the number of KKT points is polynomially bounded?!

Comment: Even the "nice, differentiable" case is not easy. Nonconvex quadratic programming is known to be NP-hard.

Comment: Actually, even convex quadratic programming is np in the general case. I think it was clear what I meant by "nice" in this case tho

Answer (score 0):

**First special case**

One special case that is tractable is when the extreme points of $S$ can be enumerated, and their number is polynomial in the description length of $S$. For example, it can happen when $S$ is polyhedral with a relatively small number of vertices.

In general, maximizing a convex function over a convex set $S$ is equivalent to maximizing a convex function over the extreme points of $S$. So you can exhaustively enumerate $f(x)$ over the extreme points of $S$, and choose the maximum.

**Second special case**

When $S$ is an ellipsoid itself. That is, when
$$
S = \{ x : x^T B x \leq \alpha \}
$$ 
In that case you have the well known TRS (Trust Region Subproblem) problem, for which there exist many algorithms. One well-known algorithm is described in the paper "Solving the Trust-Region Subprobblem by a Generalized Eigenvalue Problem" by Adachi et. al.